# Edit Files Only Using Linux Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, editor

I have the following file in linux

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pinboard>
 <backdrop style=""></backdrop>
 <icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>
 <icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>
</pinboard>
```

I want to add more lines like

```
     <icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>
```

between

```
 <pinboard>
 </pinboard>
```

preferably before the last

I only want to use linux shell

Comment: Why don't you try a XML parser?

Comment: What is that , is that available in shell

Comment: Look for `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: Cant I do some thing without installing external software ?

Comment: Learn `ed` or maybe `sed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you can use the stream editor, SED, for this. You can either insert a line before the `</pinboard>` or append a line after `<pinboard>`. Both approaches use the same syntax:

To append:

```
sed '/<pinboard>/a <icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>' /path/to/file.xml
```

To insert:

```
sed '/<\/pinboard>/i <icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>' /path/to/file.xml
```

These output changes to the standard out. If you want changes done inline (in the file itself) add the `-i` switch:

```
sed -i '/<pinboard>/a <icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>' /path/to/file.xml
```

You can use this as a function in bash to populate the variables if you wish:

```
append()
{
    local file_name="$1"
    local x="$2"
    local y="$3"
    local label="$4"
    local args="$5"
    sed -i '/<pinboard>/a <icon x="$x" y="$y" label="$label" args="$args"></icon>' $file_name
}

append /some/file.xml 5 20 "Good Label" "--some-arg"
```

Comment: I love you .. Specially for the -i

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...

Use nano or vi?
vi should come by default with your operating system...
nano can easily be installed using your package manager... I prefer nano cuz its easier to use (as compared to cryptic looking commands in vi, but then on some systems you would need to install the nano binary)

Sorry I had to post this here cuz I can't add a comment...

Comment: I would have used Nano or VI .. But i am not doing this my self . I want to do it pragmatically .. all i want is a shell function that takes my string and inserts it into the file before </pinboard>

Answer (score 0):

For well-formated XML file. awk can also be used to do this. something like the followings.

```
cat /some/file.xml | \
awk \
 '{ if ( $0 ~ <\/pinboard> ) {
      print "<icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>"
      print $0 
    } else {
      print $0 
    }
  }
' > newfile.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

A short script provides a straight-forward solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$1" ] || {
    printf "\n Error, insufficient input. usage: %s xml_filename [endtag] [line2add]\n\n" "${0//*\/}"
    exit 1
}

tag="${2:-</pinboard>}"
l2add="${3:-<icon x=\"\" y=\"\" label=\"\" args=\"\"></icon>}"

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do        # read each line in XML file
    if [ "$line" = "$tag" ]; then               # if line = tag, begin saving lines
        printf "%s\n" "$l2add"                  # print line to add (l2add)
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "$line"                       # print every line
done <"$1"

exit 0
```

**usage:**

```
parsexml.sh xml_filename [endtag] [line2add]

    endtag (default): </pinboard>
    l2add  (default): <icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>
```

**output:**

```
$ ./parsexml.sh dat/xml.dat
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pinboard>
<backdrop style=""></backdrop>
<icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>
<icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>
<icon x="" y="" label="" args=""></icon>
</pinboard>
```